# Drupal 7: broken AT subtheme pixture reloaded

Tags: drupal-7, themes

I foolishly updated the version of Adaptive Theme from 7.x 2.3 to 3.2 and broke my Pixture Reloaded theme which requires AT 2.3. I restored AT to 2.3 BUT several blocks are not visible (in particular the Content block. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this before my community group gets upset that their site is offline?

Comment: I see a bunch of errors in dblog - Undefined variable: skip_link_target - how do I define them?

Comment: I spent some time deleting the new version of AT and now the site is functional